# How to resolve "E: Malformed entry 1 in list file" in WSL Ubuntu? The list file is CORRECT

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, npm, command-line-interface, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just followed the Atlas CLI installation instructions on MongoDB's website [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/cli/stable/install-atlas-cli/#std-label-install-atlas-cli) down to this part:

1. Create the list file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list` for your version of Ubuntu. Replace `6.0` with your edition of MongoDB.
2. `echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/bionic/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list`

There is a resulting file at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, and inside, it only has:

```
deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/bionic/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse
```

But when I run `sudo apt-get update`, it says:

```
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I technically have version 6.3, but there is nothing there if I go to that URL in my browser. Nevertheless, I've separately tried:

- changing the filename and contents to 6.3 instead of 6.0
- removing the `[ arch=amd64,arm64 ]` or `multiverse` bit just to narrow down the issue
- recopying and pasting the part in quotes directly into the file from the website
- deleting-recreating the file
- updating to the latest Ubuntu version?!

The error doesn't change with any of this. When I copy-paste the LIST file URL into my browser, it goes to the right place, so it has to be correct.

I do not know if this is connected to WSL, which causes all sorts of mysterious issues. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same thing. Reviewing the contents of the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list file for my version of Ubuntu (not the same as yours, v20.04 in my case) showed the following:

```
deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/focal/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse
```

However, that seems to be missing a parameter. I had a prior installation of MongoDB v5.0, and the contents then were as follows:

```
deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse
```

Comparing the two, I decided to manually change the line for the 6.0 install so that it's in the same format as it used to be for 5.0:

```
deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse
```

That worked for me on my Ubuntu 20.04 installation. I believe you're facing the same situation in your installation of Bionic Beaver (18.04) (best OS animal name ever, in my opinion).

In your case, you have the following:

```
deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/bionic/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse
```

I believe - though I could be wrong - it should be as follows:

```
deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse
```

Or, it might be easier to run what I believe the full command for Bionic Beaver should have been on the MongoDB site:

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list
```

Following that, attempt another "sudo apt update". I hope that works!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ended up switching to Git Bash on Windows because WSL causes me problems all the time, but if I need to do this another time I will reference your suggestions.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked for me. For a list of distributions, see https://repo.mongodb.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/